If X is a statement, is the collection of all interpretations of X a set?

Let X be a statement

Let SI be the predicate set of interpretations of X

Let IX be the predicate interpretation of X

Let NA be the predicate not contained in A

∃A∃B(SI(A)∧IX(B)∧NA(B))→∀A∃B(SI(A)→IX(B)∧NA(B))

∃A∃B(SI(A)∧IX(B)∧NA(B)) translates to: For some A and B, A is a set of interpretations of X, B is an interpretation of X, and B is not in A.

∀A∃B(SI(A)→IX(B)∧NA(B)) translates to: For all A there exists B, such that if A is a set of interpretations of X, then B is an interpretation of X and B is not in A.

∀A∃B(SI(A)→IX(B)∧NA(B))=∀A(SI(A)→∃B(IX(B)∧NA(B)))

∀A(SI(A)→∃B(IX(B)∧NA(B)))=∀A(¬∃B(IX(B)∧NA(B))→¬SI(A))

∀A(¬∃B(IX(B)∧NA(B))→¬SI(A)) translates to: For all A, if there is no interpretation of X that is not in A, then A is not a set of interpretations of X.



No. Interpretations depend on a set selected as the domain and the collection of all sets is not a set. If you fix some set as the domain then all interpretations on that domain will form a set, but you may not get all interpretations this way even "up to isomorphism". Some statements (expressing first-order theories, for example) have distinctive interpretations on domains of arbitrarily high cardinality by Löwenheim–Skolem.

"hermeneutics" is the wrong tag here.

What are you trying to convey with your long formulas? Two remarks may be useful: (i) in order to "prove" something, we have to start from some "starting points": either common agreed axioms or clearly stated assumptions. (ii) a proper symbolic representation of statements is useful if we start from a preliminary analysis of the problem to be discussed trying to clearly identify the basic concepts, i.e. the terms naming entity and properties that occur in the statements: axioms and "theorems".

@MauroALLEGRANZA, by X is a statement, I mean it could be any statement whether it be in natural language or formal language. X can even be a statement from the Bible.

@Conifold: I am using statement here in a broad sense to mean any statement like a statement from the Bible. Also, I am using interpretation in its natural language sense, not in a mathematical sense.

@MauroALLEGRANZA, also I disagree with what you said regarding hermeneutics as being the wrong tag. For I am using the word interpretation in its natural language sense.

If you are using "set" also in its natural language sense of any vaguely described 'collection' then you are in trouble, it produces well-known paradoxes. And the question becomes uninteresting, all of anything can be loosely called a "set".

@Conifold, is Russell’s paradox even a paradox or is it just a version of Skolem’s theorem?
